# Set some folder on Apache server as a defaul folder

Tags: php, apache, cpanel

I'm developing some web based application based on PHP.

I have some folder structure that will be located inside the public html file.

I'd like to make it work so that when a user types for ex. http://mysite.com/  he/she gets into http://mysite.com/public but I don't want the user to know that he/she is inside public, the user should think that his directly inside public_html folder.

Any hints?

P.S. I'm doing it on hosted server, so I have access with only Cpanel, I'm not the admin of the server.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to use [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html) or  [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for this. How much of cPanel is available to you? How much does you host let you do?

I'll just have to have a look through my WHM server to work out how to do Aliases, but you can do rewrites with a .htaccess file. I would recommend Aliases over rewrites thought, as they are less complicated and less resource-hungry.

**EDIT**

Just been into my root login for our WHM/cPanel based server, and I can't find any way to use mod_alias - I think this is probably because it would require an Apache restart. You will have to use mod_rewrite.

Put this in a `.htaccess` file in public_html:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an [addon domain](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/AddonDomains) and point it to `/public_html/public` directory.

**Edit:**

Parked domain should work too.

Comment: A bit messy, plus you may get billed extra for it depending on how evil your hosting company are...

Comment: Not that messy, leaves `/public_html` clean. But I agree that with evil hosting company addon domains may cost extra.